# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=(y+1)(y-1)$ that passes through the point $(x,y)=(1,0)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need a bit of help to solve the following problem:

Solve
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=(y+1)(y-1)
$$
that passes through the point $(x,y)=(1,0)$

I know it is separable and when I integrate I get
$$
-\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(y+1\right) 
+ \frac{1}{2} \ln \left(y-1\right) = x+c_1 
$$
and when I sub in $(x,y)=(1,0)$ I can get it down to $.5\ln(-1)=0+c$ which is undefined. Am I on the right track? I am at a bit of a wall and definitely need some help

Comment: First, the integration should give you logarithms of *absolute values*; i.e., $\ln|y+1|$ and $\ln|y-1|$. That's why you get the nonsense of "$\ln(-1)$". Second, you plug in $x=1$, not $x=0$. Thirdly, you need to consider the possibility of $y=1$ and of $y=-1$, before you divide by either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(y-1)(y+1) \implies \frac{dy}{(y+1)(y-1)}=dx$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{2} \int \left( \frac{1}{y-1}-\frac{1}{y+1} \right) dy=\int dx$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{2} \ln \left |\frac{y-1}{y+1} \right |=x+A$$
Use $y(1)=0$ to get $A=-1.$